# How can I jump from the sidebar in Nautilus to the content area at right?

Tags: fedora, nautilus, gnome3

How can I jump from the sidebar in Nautilus to the content area at right? I want the keyboard focus to be inside the content area of the folder, so that I can start typing to initiate a search inside the folder. I'm using Fedora 15, Gnome3.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found a key, but you can use <kbd>F9</kbd> to switch off the side pane, then you can have the keyboard focus in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply start typing name of folder or file which you want to open and cursor will jump to that folder/file. If you want to find files or folders deeper inside folder you use Ctrl+F for that.

Comment: Not if the focus is inside the sidebar, then typing something would result in searching through stuff in the sidebar, but not in the contents area.